# Is there a short form for accessing dictionary values in for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a short form for accessing dictionary values in for loop in Python?

I have the following example code:

```
dict = [{"name": "testdata"}, {"name": "testdata2"}]

for x in dict:
    print(x["name"])
```

Is there a way to write the dictionary key directly into the line of the for loop, e.g.

```
dict = [{"name": "testdata"}, {"name": "testdata2"}]

for x in dict["name"]:
    print(x)
```

which obviously does not work. But the main idea is that x should already be the string "testdata" or "testdata2". I want to avoid this:

```
dict = [{"name": "testdata"}, {"name": "testdata2"}]

for x in dict:
    x = x["name"]
```

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't overwrite the builtin `dict`, much less with something that's a list.

Comment: if there is a way to store your data differently i would highly recommend to store it like this: {'name': ['testdata', 'testdata2']} if the dict key is the same for all data. also like @deceze writing the data into a variable called 'dict' is really bad since you override the actual dict class.

Comment: I can not store the data differently as this is how I get it. This is also not the actual code but I see that this is a bad example name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't destructure a dict on assignment, so the only way would be to loop over an iterable that contains only the one value you want, e.g.:

```
for x in (i['name'] for i in dict):
    ...
```

or:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for x in map(itemgetter('name'), dict):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get around calling the key for each element but you can do it in a list comprehension to convert your list of dictionaries to a list of `'name'` elements and then loop through that:

```
dict = [{"name": "testdata"}, {"name": "testdata2"}]

for name in [x["name"] for x in dict]:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Note that using a list comprehension here is much more expensive than a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74520722/476).

Comment: @deceze: My understanding is that the list comprehension is more expensive with regards to memory, while the generator is more expensive with regards to processing time due to the need to call `__next__()` on each item.

Comment: Yes, but you'll probably be hard pressed to find a real difference in speed of iteration, while you can easily see massive differences in memory consumption, depending on how large your input is.